# `pymdownx.highlight` --- where do I find the "highlight" stylesheet used by syntax highlighting on fenced blocks?

Tags: python, html, css, markdown

I've been trying to write a Flask app which automatically converts Markdown into an HTML that will get served as the response.

Consider the following toy snippet:

````py
import markdown
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['pymdownx.superfences'])

s = '''
```py3
import hello_world
\```  # ignore the backslash here
'''.strip()

print(md.convert(s))
````

And it produces the following output:

```html
<div class="highlight"><pre><span></span><code><span class="kn">import</span> <span class="nn">hello_world</span>
</code></pre></div>
```

Notice the `class="highlight"` there in the `div`.  My produced HTML has no syntax highlighting, obviously---because I don't have a stylesheet that defines that "highlight" class.  But for the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do with `pymdownx` in order to find that stylesheet with `highlight`.  Is there a property or function I need to access?  Is there something separate that I need to include in the CSS on my own?

I'm pretty lost, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `highlight` class is included so that the block can be targeted by JavaScript code formatters such as [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). The actual highlighting here is in the `span` classes that appear in your generated output, like `kn` and `nn`. You can generate a stylesheet for this with Pygments like so:

```
pygmentize -S default -f html > desired/path/to/stylesheet.css
```

Which includes (among others) the rules:

```css
.kn { color: #008000; font-weight: bold } /* Keyword.Namespace */
.nn { color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold } /* Name.Namespace */
```

[List of Pygments supported styles](https://pygments.org/styles/)